# Why is my Spring kafka consumer slow at consuming records?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

So I have a spring kafka setup so that it polls for 5000 records each fetch.

- Deserialization of those 5000 records takes about 2 seconds
- Processing on the listener for those 5000 records takes about 120 seconds

That means I can only handle about 40 records per second, which is pretty low.

But when I check actuator on how long the listener method takes to execute, it says in average 0.00013 seconds, that times 5000 should be 0.65 seconds. So I imagine spring is taking around 119.45 seconds do handle those records to my listener.

Anyone could please help me understand the situation, I should be much faster processing those but I can't see the reason why that is not the case.

My current configuration is as follows:

```java
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, MarketChangesProtocolBuffer.MarketChanges> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-group" );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class );
        props.put( ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS,
                MarketChangesDeserializer.class );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest" );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 5000 );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 1000 );
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, 10000 );
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>( props );
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, MarketChangesProtocolBuffer.MarketChanges>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MarketChangesProtocolBuffer.MarketChanges> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory( consumerFactory() );
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout( 3000 );
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode( ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD );
        factory.setErrorHandler( new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                new FixedBackOff( 2000, 2 ) ) );
        return factory;
    }
```

And the listener:

```java
@Component
public class ScoringListenerService {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "test-topic", groupId = "test-group")
    public void listenGroup( MarketChangesProtocolBuffer.MarketChanges marketChanges,
            ConsumerRecordMetadata metadata ) {
        // some business logic...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue is the acknowledge mode, since I am using `AckMode.RECORD`, each time the listener is called on the return a synchronous call is made to commit the offset  and Spring waits for the response before processing the next record. Changing it to `AckMode.BATCH` greatly increases performance as commits are posponed untill all messages returned on the poll are processed.

Comment: Keep in mind this introduces at-least-once delivery and you will need to deal with duplicate consumption, if that matters

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be Spring:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So71681525Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71681525Application.class, args);
    }

    int count;

    StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();

    @KafkaListener(id = "so71681525", topics = "so71681525")
    void listen(String in) {
        if (count++ == 1) {
            this.watch.start();
        }
        else if (count == 50_000) {
            perf();
        }
    }

    private void perf() {
        this.watch.stop();
        System.out.println(this.watch.prettyPrint());
        System.out.println(this.count + " @ " + (int) ((count) / (this.watch.getTotalTimeSeconds()) / 1000) + "k/s");
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so71681525").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 50_000).forEach(i -> template.send("so71681525", "foo"));
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=5000
```

```
StopWatch '': running time = 140801968 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
140801968  100%  

50000 @ 355k/s
```

You need to profile your application.